# Entity Framework with working for mySQL Entity class

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

I have this configuration:

```
<connectionStrings>
<!--<add name="NREticaretContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDBSqlServer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mypass;Timeout=20;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
<add name="NREticaretContext"
     connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=myDBMySQL;Uid=root;Pwd=mypass;port=3306;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

if I use first config setting(SQL Server) everythicg works fine in my project.
But when I try to use second connection(mySQL) for mySQL connector which uses mySQL Entity Framework, application keeps on saying:

"Model compatibility cannot be checked because the EdmMetadata type was not included in the model. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions."

I have tried using :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();            
    }
```

in my Context class but it keeps on giving the same error...
Your suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Connector /NET experiences some problems with EF 4.1 at the moment.
Try turning off the Initialization Strategy `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`
I recommend you to take a look at the [Code First Support article](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html) at our blog. It describes some peculiarities of working with Code First in [dotConnect for MySQL](http://devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/).